# Matlab pass data to other thread

Tags: multithreading, matlab

Is there a way to pass Matlab data to another Matlab thread? I'm importing data from C++ to Matlab and want to pass this data to another function, which loops permanently. C++ opens a new Matlab window, so variables can not be shared easily. One way would be to write the imported data to a file and read this file in the other loop, but this takes quite some time. Is there someone with a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard solution costs money: [Parallel Computing Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/parallel-computing/).

Comment: Just to be clear, the MATLAB interpreter is single-threaded, you cannot run MATLAB code on mutliple threads. The Parallel Computing Toolbox allows you to easily run your code in other MATLAB processes via clusters, either using the in-built 'local' cluster, which creates one MATLAB worker per physical core on your machine, or using other machines via MDCS.